# Divide two 2D arrays element wise

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two 2D list

```
list1 = {{x,a1},{y,a2},{z,a3}}
list2 = {{x,b1},{y,b2},{z,b3}}
```

I want a list that divides only the second element of each element of the 2D array.

```
list3 = {{x,a1/b1},{y,a2/b2},{z,a3/b3}}
```

I know how to do this using a loop, but I want to know is there an elegant way using mathematica?

Comment: Some options: `MapThread[{First[#1], Last[#1]/Last[#2]} &, {list1, list2}]` or `Thread[{list1[[All, 1]], list1[[All, 2]]/list2[[All, 2]]}]`

Comment: `list1/{1, Last@#} & /@ list2`

Comment: `list1/(ReplacePart[#, 1 -> 1] & /@ list2)`

Comment: @Syed - you are missing parentheses around denominator, i.e., `list1/({1, Last@#} & /@ list2)`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon: It is always a good idea to have parentheses. Is it not evaluating on your machine, as I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkNpd.png).

Comment: @Syed - what you have linked is not evaluated like what is in your comment. Structuring the expression as a fraction is equivalent to putting parentheses around `{1, Last@#} & /@ list2`. Compare with just copying the code from your comment and executing it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I see that every solution works. Whoever wants to post the answer is most welcome to. Since my original lists are very large, I will accept that answer that will be the fastest.

Comment: @sslucifer - Since you will be doing timing tests, post your own answer to include the timing for the different approaches. You don't need to show long lists. Use `list1 = Array[{x[#], a[#]} &, 1000]; list2 = Array[{x[#], b[#]} &, 1000];` Then for the different methods: `RepeatedTiming[list3 = ( ...)[[1 ;; 3]]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon : I see what you mean, Thanks for pointing it out. I copy pasted from my notebook and didn't know that  parentheses were put there for me. Will be careful to copy and execute code myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list3 = list1;
list3[[All, 2]] = list3[[All, 2]]/list2[[All, 2]];
list3
```

> ```
> {{x, a1/b1}, {y, a2/b2}, {z, a3/b3}}
> ```

Also

```
list1 / Thread[{1, list2[[All, 2]]}]
```

> ```
> {{x, a1/b1}, {y, a2/b2}, {z, a3/b3}}
> ```

and

```
SubsetMap[# / list2[[All, 2]]&, list1, {All, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{x, a1/b1}, {y, a2/b2}, {z, a3/b3}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A few more possibilities

```
a = {{x, a1}, {y, a2}, {z, a3}};

b = {{x, b1}, {y, b2}, {z, b3}};
```

Using `SequenceCases` with `Riffle`"

```
SequenceCases[Riffle[a, b], {a_, b_} :> {a[[1]], a[[2]] / b[[2]]}]
```

[image]

Using `Cases` with `Transpose`

```
Cases[Transpose[{a, b}], {a_, b_} :> {a[[1]], a[[2]] / b[[2]]}]
```

[image]

Using `GroupBy`

```
GroupBy[Join[a, b], First -> Last, Apply @ Divide]
```

[image]

Using `Merge` and `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
Merge[Apply @ Divide] @ MapApply[Rule] @ Join[a, b]
```

[image]

`Association` to `List`

```
KeyValueMap[List][%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{x, a1}, {y, a2}, {z, a3}};

b = {{x, b1}, {y, b2}, {z, b3}};
```

---

Using `GatherBy` and `Replace` at level `1`:

```
rule = {{a__}, {b__}} :> {First@{a}, Divide @@ Last /@ {{a}, {b}}};

Replace[GatherBy[Join @@ {a, b}, First], rule, {1}]
```

> {{x, a1/b1}, {y, a2/b2}, {z, a3/b3}}